# Difference between these 'generic' syntaxes in Java

Tags: java, generics

Consider this:

```
public abstract class AbstractHibernateDao< T extends Serializable > {
  private T clazz;
}
```

And this:

```
public abstract class AbstractHibernateDao< T extends Serializable > {
    private Class< T > clazz;
}
```

I am able to compile both - so I definitely did some basic checks here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
private T clazz;
```

Here `clazz` can hold any type, which is of type Serializable, even your custom class object, if it is of type Serializable.

In this case, the name says it is a class (`clazz`), but the value need to be Class object.

---

```
private Class< T > clazz;
```

Here, it is the *Type* of the `Class`. [Class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html) is a generic type, so here clazz can hold only **Class object** which Type is of Serializable.

Comment: "Class object which is of type Serializable." No, this has nothing to do with the serializability of an instance of `java.lang.Class`. Instead, it matters that `clazz` can be assigned to a `Class<? extends Serializable>`.

Comment: @hexafraction I got your point. I corrected the wording, "Class object which Type is of Serializable". Thanks for identifying.

Answer (score 11):

- In case of `T clazz` we expect an *instance* of a class,
- In case of `Class< T > clazz` we expect an instance of `Class` which describes `T` (class *literal*).

So let's say that as `T` we will use `Integer`. In that case:

- In the first example, `clazz` will allow us to store `1`, `2`, etc.
- But in the second example it will expect `Integer.class`.

Answer (score 3):

The first one creates a variable clazz of type T.

The second creates a variable clazz of type Class, which is a generic type and is parameterised by T. Compare with a List<T>, i.e. a list of T's.

Answer (score 3):

In the first you get an instance of T, and in the second you'll get an instance of class of T (basically, what you'll get from calling `clazz.getClass()` in the first case).